# How can I remove 'Using temporary ' and speed up my query

Tags: mysql, optimization

Hi I was working for hours to speed up this query using indexes, but its useless.. im tyring to optimize by eliminating 'Using temporary' and using only indexes. I wonder if there is another alternative to speed up this query??

query :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
    tbl_dv_fg.id,
    IFNULL(
      tbl_dv_fg.nb_action_rea / tbl_dv_fg.nb_action_total,
      0
    ) AS txRea,
    tbl_dv_fg.num_cmde AS numcmde,
    IF(tbl_fgp.NUMCMDE IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS isPlurale,
    IF(
      tbl_dv_fg.relance_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d'),
      0,
      1
    ) AS DateRelanceArrivee,
    DATE_FORMAT(
      IFNULL(
        tbl_fg.szdatevente,
        tbl_fgp.szdatevente
      ),
      '%d/%m/%Y'
    ) AS szdatevente,
    DATE_FORMAT(
      tbl_pilotage.date_mada,
      '%d/%m/%Y'
    ) AS dateMadaPilotage,
    DATE_FORMAT(
      tbl_pilotage.date_mada_eng,
      '%d/%m/%Y'
    ) AS dateMadaEngPilotage,
    DATE_FORMAT(
      tbl_pilotage.date_liv_clt_conv,
      '%d/%m/%Y'
    ) AS dateLivCltConv,
    IFNULL(
      tbl_fg.szdatevente,
      tbl_fgp.szdatevente
    ) AS szdateventeSort,
    tbl_pilotage.date_mada AS dateMadaPilotageSort,
    tbl_pilotage.date_mada_eng AS dateMadaEngPilotageSort,
    tbl_pilotage.date_liv_clt_conv AS dateLivCltConvSort,
    tbl_pilotage.ord_c AS ordC,
    CONCAT(
      tbl_dv_fg.sznomclient,
      ' ',
      tbl_dv_fg.szprenomclient
    ) AS CLIENT,
    CONCAT(
      tbl_user.user_nom,
      ' ',
      tbl_user.user_prenom
    ) AS vendeur,
    DATE_FORMAT(
      tbl_livraison.livraison_date_facture,
      '%d/%m/%Y'
    ) AS dateFacture,
    IFNULL(
      tbl_fg.SZMARQUE,
      tbl_fgp.SZMARQUE
    ) AS SZMARQUE,
    IFNULL(
      tbl_fg.SZMODELE,
      tbl_fgp.SZMODELE
    ) AS SZMODELE 
  FROM
    `tbl_dv_fg` 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_fg_plural` 
      ON (
        tbl_dv_fg.num_cmde = tbl_fg_plural.num_cmde 
        AND tbl_dv_fg.affaire_id = tbl_fg_plural.affaire_id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_fg` 
      ON (
        tbl_dv_fg.num_cmde = tbl_fg.NUMCMDE 
        AND tbl_dv_fg.affaire_id = tbl_fg.user_rrf
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_fg` `tbl_fgp` 
      ON (
        tbl_fg_plural.user_id = tbl_fgp.user_id 
        AND tbl_fg_plural.fg_id = tbl_fgp.id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_pilotage` 
      ON (
        tbl_dv_fg.NUM_CMDE = tbl_pilotage.num_cde_sed 
        AND tbl_dv_fg.AFFAIRE_ID = tbl_pilotage.rrf
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_user` 
      ON (tbl_dv_fg.id_user = tbl_user.id) 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_livraison` 
      ON (
        tbl_pilotage.chassis = tbl_livraison.livraison_vin
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `ged_tbl_document_dv` `dv_document_1` 
      ON (
        tbl_dv_fg.id = dv_document_1.dv_id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `ged_tbl_document_type` `document_type_1` 
      ON (
        dv_document_1.document_type_id = document_type_1.document_type_id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `ged_tbl_document_dv` `dv_document_2` 
      ON (
        tbl_dv_fg.id = dv_document_2.dv_id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `ged_tbl_document_type` `document_type_2` 
      ON (
        dv_document_2.document_type_id = document_type_2.document_type_id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `ged_tbl_document_dv` `dv_document_3` 
      ON (
        tbl_dv_fg.id = dv_document_3.dv_id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `ged_tbl_document_type` `document_type_3` 
      ON (
        dv_document_3.document_type_id = document_type_3.document_type_id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `ged_tbl_document_dv` `dv_document_4` 
      ON (
        tbl_dv_fg.id = dv_document_4.dv_id
      ) 
    LEFT JOIN `ged_tbl_document_type` `document_type_4` 
      ON (
        dv_document_4.document_type_id = document_type_4.document_type_id
      ) 
  WHERE tbl_dv_fg.affaire_id = '00001154' 
    AND (
      (
        (
          (
            (
              (
                (
                  (
                    (
                      (
                        (
                          (
                            (
                              (
                                (
                                  (
                                    (
                                      (
                                        (
                                          (
                                            (
                                              (
                                                (
                                                  tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '811' 
                                                  OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '789'
                                                ) 
                                                OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '790'
                                              ) 
                                              OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '791'
                                            ) 
                                            OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10654'
                                          ) 
                                          OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10112'
                                        ) 
                                        OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10246'
                                      ) 
                                      OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '792'
                                    ) 
                                    OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '11381'
                                  ) 
                                  OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10152'
                                ) 
                                OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10133'
                              ) 
                              OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10983'
                            ) 
                            OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10113'
                          ) 
                          OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '797'
                        ) 
                        OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '807'
                      ) 
                      OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '298'
                    ) 
                    OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10245'
                  ) 
                  OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '11151'
                ) 
                OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '808'
              ) 
              OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '809'
            ) 
            OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10763'
          ) 
          OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '810'
        ) 
        OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '11681'
      ) 
      OR tbl_dv_fg.id_user = '10502'
    ) 
    AND tbl_dv_fg.nb_action_rea != tbl_dv_fg.nb_action_total 
    AND dv_document_1.cond_valide = 1 
    AND dv_document_2.cond_valide = 1 
    AND dv_document_3.cond_valide = 1 
    AND dv_document_4.cond_valide = 1 
    AND (
      (
        (
          document_type_1.document_type_id = 129 
          AND (
            dv_document_1.document_dv_statut = 0 
            OR dv_document_1.document_dv_statut IS NULL
          )
        ) 
        OR (
          document_type_2.document_type_id = 53 
          AND (
            dv_document_2.document_dv_statut = 0 
            OR dv_document_2.document_dv_statut IS NULL
          )
        )
      ) 
      OR (
        (
          document_type_3.document_type_id = 40 
          AND (
            dv_document_3.document_dv_statut = 0 
            OR dv_document_3.document_dv_statut IS NULL
          )
        ) 
        OR (
          document_type_4.document_type_id = 138 
          AND (
            dv_document_4.document_dv_statut = 0 
            OR dv_document_4.document_dv_statut IS NULL
          )
        )
      )
    ) 
    AND tbl_dv_fg.deleted_at IS NULL
```

Explain statement :

```
      id  select_type  table            type    possible_keys                                key              key_len  ref                                                          rows  Extra                               
------  -----------  ---------------  ------  -------------------------------------------  ---------------  -------  ---------------------------------------------------------  ------  ------------------------------------
     1  SIMPLE       tbl_dv_fg        range   PRIMARY,tbl_dv_fg_FI_1,affaire_id            tbl_dv_fg_FI_1   4        (NULL)                                                      10426  Using where; Using temporary        
     1  SIMPLE       tbl_fg_plural    eq_ref  numcmde                                      numcmde          178      manperf.tbl_dv_fg.num_cmde,manperf.tbl_dv_fg.affaire_id         1  Using index                         
     1  SIMPLE       tbl_fg           ref     commande,idx_NUMCMDE,idx_numcmde_user_rrf    commande         180      manperf.tbl_dv_fg.affaire_id,manperf.tbl_dv_fg.num_cmde         1                                      
     1  SIMPLE       tbl_fgp          eq_ref  PRIMARY,idx_fg_multi3                        PRIMARY          8        manperf.tbl_fg_plural.user_id,manperf.tbl_fg_plural.fg_id       1                                      
     1  SIMPLE       tbl_pilotage     ref     idx_num_cde_sed,idx_rrf,idx_num_cde_sed_rrf  idx_num_cde_sed  20       manperf.tbl_dv_fg.num_cmde                                      1                                      
     1  SIMPLE       tbl_user         eq_ref  PRIMARY                                      PRIMARY          4        manperf.tbl_dv_fg.id_user                                       1                                      
     1  SIMPLE       tbl_livraison    ref     vin                                          vin              57       manperf.tbl_pilotage.chassis                                    1                                      
     1  SIMPLE       dv_document_1    ref     Unique,idx_statut_dv                         Unique           4        manperf.tbl_dv_fg.id                                           75  Using where; Distinct               
     1  SIMPLE       document_type_1  eq_ref  PRIMARY                                      PRIMARY          4        manperf.dv_document_1.document_type_id                          1  Using index; Distinct               
     1  SIMPLE       dv_document_2    ref     Unique,idx_statut_dv                         Unique           4        manperf.dv_document_1.dv_id                                    75  Using where; Distinct               
     1  SIMPLE       document_type_2  eq_ref  PRIMARY                                      PRIMARY          4        manperf.dv_document_2.document_type_id                          1  Using index; Distinct               
     1  SIMPLE       dv_document_3    ref     Unique,idx_statut_dv                         Unique           4        manperf.dv_document_2.dv_id                                    75  Using where; Distinct               
     1  SIMPLE       document_type_3  eq_ref  PRIMARY                                      PRIMARY          4        manperf.dv_document_3.document_type_id                          1  Using index; Distinct               
     1  SIMPLE       dv_document_4    ref     Unique,idx_statut_dv                         Unique           4        manperf.tbl_dv_fg.id                                           75  Using where; Distinct               
     1  SIMPLE       document_type_4  eq_ref  PRIMARY                                      PRIMARY          4        manperf.dv_document_4.document_type_id                          1  Using where; Using index; Distinct
```

Comment: That query smells like EAV on steroids.  Not good.  "Using temporary" is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has many issues that difficult optimisation.

You use `LEFT JOIN` in several tables where `INNER JOIN` should suffice (e.g. all cases of `ged_tbl_document_dv` and `ged_tbl_document_type`).

You include tables that you later never really require (e.g. all cases of `ged_tbl_document_type`), so removing all of them wouldn't impact the result (replace all instances of `document_type_id` from `ged_tbl_document_type` to `ged_tbl_document_dv` in the where clause).

You left join the table `ged_tbl_document_dv` four times, when one should suffice with inner join:

```
JOIN ged_tbl_document_dv doc ON (
  tbl_dv_fg.id = doc.dv_id AND 
  doc.cond_valide = 1 AND
  NULLIF(doc.document_dv_statut, 0) IS NULL AND
  doc.document_type_id IN (40, 53, 129, 138))
```

This query doesn't really require `DISTINCT`, because it includes a primary key. If you have any duplicated rows, you're then performing a join incorrectly, and you should either use a subselect within the SELECT clause, or adopt a different your strategy. The undesired duplicates are likely coming from either `tbl_pilotage` or `tbl_fg_plural`.

The more tables you join (especially if you use any OUTER JOIN), then the more complex the possibly query plans become, and the more likely your RDBMS will be to choose one that doesn't work very well. If you keep your queries as compact and minimalist as possible, the queries will be more likely to run more efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

From comments:

`DISTINCT` is very similar to `GROUP BY <all selected columns>` and getting rid of the temporary table may be impossible when joining many tables as the server needs it to check uniqueness of the returned rows.

[Covering indexes](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) (`Using index`) are quite useful when you need to get the top performance.

I prefer `IN()` instead of multiple ORs on the same column as it is more readable. My previous statement about IN having better performance seems to be wrong.

You don't have to quote numbers when you compare them to a numeric column but you must quote them when the column is (var)char for indexes to work.

Default `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is too small for most applications, give it 60-80% of available RAM if you have most data in InnoDB tables, a bit less when you have some MyISAM too, and give some to the `key_buffer_size` - but only for myisam indexes, it caches data in the filesystem cache ("free" memory of your system).

Comment: @jkavalik covering indexes are useful indeed but i hesitated because I have more than 20 columns which mean a BIG composite index.

Comment: @YassineLAADIDI 20 columns from one table? Yes, there are drawbacks to big indexes - slower updates and more space/memory needed. You can benchmark it to see if the speedup is worth it or not.